# Configuration of `PlotLayout` as "Row"/"Column"

Tags: plotting, version-12

A long awaited feature has finally been implemented in Mathematica v12: the multi-panel plots via `PlotLayout`!

Demos are here:

1. http://www.wolfram.com/language/12/core-visualization/create-a-column-of-plots.html?product=mathematica
2. http://www.wolfram.com/language/12/core-visualization/create-a-column-of-plots.html?product=mathematica

By reading the documentation and [a CEO live video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-ib7yR13Yk&t=777s), it seems extra `Method` option can be provided for better formatting of ticks (e.g., `Method->{"GridTicks"->All}`,`Method->{"GridTicks"->"Alternating"}`). However, such options are never documented, or not explicitly provided.

*My question is:*

**What are the proper configurations of `PlotLayout` for multi-panel plots?**

Comment: In the Wolfram Technology Conference 2018, Brett Champion uses `PlotLayout->"Row"` and `PlotLayout->{"Column",2}`. Maybe there are other examples.

Comment: It looks as if `{"Row" | "Column", n_Integer?Positive}` works for `PlotLayout`.